# Root view controllers and modal dialogs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In a custom `UIViewController`, if I have a member `UINavigationController` that I initialize with `self` as the root view, like this:

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
```

then presenting a modal dialog does not hide the tab bar at the bottom of the screen. The result is that if the user switches to a different tab while a modal dialog is displayed, when they pop back to the tab that was displaying a modal dialog then subsequent calls to `presentModalViewController` do not display a modal dialog at all, even if I call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` as a result of the tab switch.

If I initialize the UINavigationController with out setting `self` as the root controller,

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

then the tab bar is hidden as expected. I've changed things in my program so that this isn't really an issue for me anymore, but I'm not sure that I understand why this is happening. Is it considered bad practice to have a navigation controller with `self` as the root, if the nav controller is going to be displaying modal dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never added self as root controller

I always have some Controller that gets a NavigationController.view added to itself.
And the first ViewController that shall be displayed in the Navigation hierarchy I then add as the rootViewController. It's just another word for "first page" (in the beginning all the naming can be quite confusing).

Example in MyProjectAppDelegate.m:

```
UITableViewController *startScreen = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startScreen];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

You also shouldn't mix UINavigationController with UITabBarController, if you want to have a tab bar in a navigationcontroller "page" you can build a custom UITabBarController.

This would show you how http://github.com/wiredbob/NavTab

(I had big problems in understanding all this view/controller nesting myself and this project really made the difference. You could say this was the code I really learned how to programm for iPhone/Mac with :DD )